# Using dummy guid's with ServiceStack's OrmLite, some fields are populated with an empty guid instead of the value. What could be causing this?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Specifically, I am trying to retrieve a row with this '00010600-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' value as the Id in my class.

I have tried using ado to retrieve the column to check and it returns the value appropriately but when I try to use Select() or GetByIdOrDefault(id), my object is returned with all the other values populated correctly except for the Id field which comes back as an empty guid.

The Id column is set as the primary key of the table.

Edit:

```
[Test]
public void Test() {
    var dbFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(_configuration.ConnectionString);

    using (var conn = dbFactory.OpenDbConnection()) {
        var nodes = conn.Select<TreeNode>();
        foreach (var node in nodes) {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

This test replicates the issue that I'm experiencing. A few Guid's that I'm experiencing the problem with are:

- 00010600-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
- 00010100-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
- 00000300-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Comment: Could you show us the code where you fill and retrieve the data? It would be start for us to try and help you.

Comment: Sorry I had to run off halfway. I've appended a code sample that recreates the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was to do with a field that was an enum in the object and a value for the field was set incorrectly with a space and could not be mapped back to the enum. This caused all the other mappings for the row to fail.

```
public static T PopulateWithSqlReader<T>(this T objWithProperties, IDataReader dataReader, FieldDefinition[] fieldDefs, Dictionary<string, int> indexCache)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var fieldDef in fieldDefs)
        {
            int index;
            if (indexCache != null)
            {
                if (!indexCache.TryGetValue(fieldDef.Name, out index))
                {
                    index = dataReader.GetColumnIndex(fieldDef.FieldName);
                    if (index == NotFound)
                    {
                        index = TryGuessColumnIndex(fieldDef.FieldName, dataReader);
                    }

                    indexCache.Add(fieldDef.Name, index);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                index = dataReader.GetColumnIndex(fieldDef.FieldName);
                if (index == NotFound)
                {
                    index = TryGuessColumnIndex(fieldDef.FieldName, dataReader);
                }
            }

            if (index == NotFound) continue;
            var value = dataReader.GetValue(index);
            fieldDef.SetValue(objWithProperties, value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex);
    } 
    return objWithProperties;
}
```

The try/catch in the method above swallows this problem and unless logging is turned on (which it should be, my bad), this issue goes unnoticed.